# Why FILTER_VALIDATE_URL return FALSE for only this url?

Tags: php, filter-var

i have the following code:

```
$url = "http://icons3.iconfinder.netdna-cdn.com/data/icons/pool/poolbird.png";

if (filter_var ($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {

    echo "Invalid Url";
    exit;

} else {

    echo "Works!";
}
```

This displays:

> invalid url (FALSE)

for the above url, but not for other simpler urls. Is this a bug? you can even access the image.

And the most important is what's the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP < 5.2.13 contains a bug in `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` that considers urls containing the '-' (http://bugs.php.net/51192).  You either need to upgrade your copy of php or use a different filtering mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

That code prints "Works!" for me. What version of PHP are you using? Can you post a link to a PHP page containing:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137080/php-filter-var-filter-validate-url).

Answer (score 1):

Running PHP 5.2.13, I get this response when trying to filter a valid URL:

```
php > var_dump(filter_var("http://www.asdf-asdf.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
bool(false)
```

This is clearly not what I woukd expect it to return. The domain is valid.

This has evidently been fixed now, and will be included in PHP 5.3.3 and 5.2.14, more info in this bugreport:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51192

Answer (score 0):

The source archive from http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.2.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror contains a strange version of ext/filter/logical_filter.c, a version I can't find in [the cvs](http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?view=log).
This version performs an "extra" test on the host part of the url

```
e = url->host + strlen(url->host);
s = url->host;

while (s < e) {
  if (!isalnum((int)*(unsigned char *)s) && *s != '_' && *s != '.') {
    goto bad_url;
  }
  s++;
}
```

which doesn't allow a hyphen in the host name like in icons3.iconfinder.netdna**-**cdn.com
Very strange and very wrong.