# How To Use ?q= To Redirect Url

Tags: html, redirect

I am trying to make a page that redirects the client to the URL after the `?q=`. So for example `http://example.com/?q=http://www.google.com` would redirect the user to `http://www.google.com`. What do I have to do to get the page to redirect depending on the URL after the `?q=`?

Comment: Server-side? Client-side? Any languages preferences? You can't do this in just plain HTML.

Comment: What kind of server side programming language that you use?

Comment: I am using PHP5 and JavaScript To Do This.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
var lnk = location.href.split( '?q=' );
location.href = lnk[1];
```

PHP

```
header( 'Location: ' . $_GET['q'] );
```

Comment: The JavaScript won't work unless `q` is the ONLY parameter in the url

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify what programming language you are using, if you are using PHP you can do this:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])) {
      header('Location: '.$_GET['q']);       

  }                 

?>
```

You can optionally validate the URL to prevent errors. Be sure that you are using a PHP version (PHP > 5.2.13). Check this question: [Why FILTER_VALIDATE_URL return FALSE for only this url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596517/why-filter-validate-url-return-false-for-only-this-url)

```
<?php

  if (isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])) {
     if(filter_var($_GET['q'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        header('Location: '.$_GET['q']); 
     }else{
        echo "Invalid URL";
     }

  }
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Makes an array out of all the variables in your address bar:

```
var query = {};
window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) { query[key] = value; });
```

Tested on a random Google search, the object looked like:

```
aqs:      "chrome.0.69i59j69i65l3j69i61j0.1762j0j4"
es_sm:    "0"
ie:       "UTF-8"
oq:       "random"
q:        "random"
sourceid: "chrome"
```

So, find your `q` variable and redirect to it:

```
var query = {};

window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) { query[key] = value; });

location.href = query['q'];
```