# Regex to ensure valid querystring

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string

I'm trying to come up with a Regex expression that I can use with Javascript .test to make sure my system is only accepting query strings in a valid format.

The format looks like this `i=1&s1=122&s2=238&s3=167&s4=756&s5=13` It can have an unlimited number of `s#=` arguments in it, so could be longer or shorter than this example.

In English the format is something like `i=1&s[1+0]=[any number > 0]&s[1+1]=[any number > 0]&s[1+2]=[any number > 0]` and so on.

Right now the regex I have is `/^([\w-]+(=[\w-]*)?(&[\w-]+(=[\w-]*)?)*)?$/` It's based on the code provided in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959662/3680712) It does an ok job of rejecting some types of invalid strings, but there are still a lot that slip through.

How can I improve this regex expression so it more accurately rejects invalid data?

Comment: `s[1+2]` how will regex perfomr arithmatic operations...how will it detect a linear increase in numbers?

Comment: If it can't that's fine. The system isn't super picky about what the keys in the key-value pairs are. I was just indicating the format in case it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can tighten things up with:

```
/^i=1(&s\d+=\d+)+$/
```

It will allow, say, `s14` to come before `s2`, but query parameters are supposed to be unordered anyway.

Comment: I think this is the best one, because it correctly maintains that the string begins with `i=1`. I made one change, since I don't need a capturing group. Final regex expression used: `^i=1(?:&s\d+=\d+)+$`

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex like

```
^i=\d+(?:&s\d+=\d+)+$
```

For example http://regex101.com/r/rP8vU5/2

Answer (score 1):

```
^i=\d+(?:&s\d+=\d+(?=&|$))+$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/14