# regular expression java for URL parameter string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to verify if the string match a regular expression or not.
The URL format is :  `key=value&key=value&....`

Key or value can be empty.

My code is :

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\w*=\\w*&(\\w *=\\w*)* ");
Matcher m = patt.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()) return true;
else return false;
```

when i enter `one=1&two=2`, it shows false whereas it should show true.
Any idea !

Comment: Escape your backslashes

Comment: By the way: Replace `if A return true; else return false;` with `return A;`

Comment: @GiladGreen Nope, his regex is good. He just needs to escape \, as it is a Java string.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/QjYyZG. You need `"\\w+=\\w+(?:&\\w+=\\w+)*"` regex. The `\w+` will match 1 or more word chars, `\w*` would allow an empty string. Well, maybe you really want to allow `=&=&=&=`, no idea. Then use `"\\w*=\\w*(?:&\\w*=\\w*)*"`. *What are the requirements?*. BTW, added another dupe - [Validate URL query string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959352/validate-url-query-string-with-regex).

Comment: Regarding the update: did you really want to match the spaces before the second `=`?

Comment: key=value&key=value&....
Empty key or value are accepted but '=' must be present (e.g. "=value", "key=").

Comment: @Henry no, i edit it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
I tried your suggestion but it does not work

Comment: @AmirChoubani: With your input string, [it works](http://ideone.com/QjYyZG) as it outputs *true*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what is the example that you tried with ?

Comment: Look at the code. `String s = "one=1&two=2";`. Just what *you* provided.

Comment: ah yes, it works.Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Well, you may also try http://ideone.com/Sa7WNv. It will match key-values where either a key or value can be empty. Is that better? `(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+)(?:&(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+))*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you need is

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+)(?:&(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+))*");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8IqvP9/1). It will match:

- `(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+)` - either 1+ word chars followed with `=` and then 0+ word chars (obligatory key, optional value) or `=` followed with 1+ word chars (optional key)
- `(?:&(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+))*` - zero or more of such sequences as above.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/Sa7WNv):

```
String s = "one=1&two=2&=3&tr=";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+)(?:&(?:\\w+=\\w*|=\\w+))*");
Matcher m = patt.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
//  => true
```

To allow whitespaces, add `\\s*` where needed. If you need to also allow non-word chars, use, say, `[\\w.-]` instead of `\w` to match word chars, `.` and `-` (keep the `-` at the end of the character class).