# Check if submitted form data is a link and starts with a certain words

Tags: php, html

I want a system where the submitted data from my input field has to be a URL and start with 'http://' or 'https://' in PHP. But when I submit the form it keeps alerting 'Invalid Link' can it be fixed?

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Title'])){
        $Title=$_POST['Title'];
    }if(isset($_POST['Description'])){
        $Description=$_POST['Description'];
    }if(isset($_POST['Link'])){
        $Link=$_POST['Link'];
    }
    if(strlen($Title) <= 5){
        echo "<script> alert('Title should be more than 5 characters!')</script>";
        exit;
    }
    if(strlen($Description) <= 5){
        echo "<script> alert('Description should be more than 5 characters!')</script>";
        exit;
    }
    $contains = "https://drive.google.com/";

    if(strlen($Link) <= 5 || !preg_match("/\b($contains)\b/", $Link)){
        echo "<script> alert('INVALID LINK!') </script>";
        exit;
    }
    else{
    echo "<script> alert('DONE!') </script>";
}
```

?>

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you wan't to check if link contains "https://drive.google.com/" or you only want to check if this is valid link?

Comment: nopes that wont be correct @Smartpal

Comment: @Rainmx93 It should start with https://drive.google.com/

Comment: then you can use substr($Link, 0, strlen($contains)) function to check if string starts with https://drive.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to check if a certain string is a URL and a valid one at that the simplest way to check would be using [validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) more specifically `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.

```
if(filter_var('https://google.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
    // Url is valid

}
else
{
    // url is no valid
}
```

However do note that strings that **do not** start with `http` or `https` are not considered valid urls. This is not any sort of bug in PHP or in any other language it's how the [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples) works.

---

If your goal is to check strictly if a string starts with `http` or `https` and only that you can simply use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.strpos.php)

```
if(strpos($url, `http`) === 0 || strpos($url, `https`) === 0) {
    // the url starts with http or https
    // strpos
}
```

Note that I'm using `=== 0` that's because `strpos` returns the position of the string or `false` if not found. You want to check if the string **starts** with `http` or `https`.

---

There's also the route of regex. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9623072/4729332) question.

Comment: Thank you! With a few changes I got it to work through your method.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your pattern consists of a complete url that you are parsing in the regex via a variable and you are not escaping the `//` in the `http://` you need to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) like below

```
if(strlen($Link) <= 5 || !preg_match('/' . preg_quote($contains, '/') . '/', $Link)){
    echo "<script> alert('INVALID LINK!') </script>";
    exit;
}
```