# Why FILTER_VALIDATE_URL doesn't work for Persian characters?

Tags: php, url

Here is [my code](https://3v4l.org/jDMdu):

```
$url = "http://localhost/myweb/qanda/1/";
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
//=> string(31) "http://localhost/myweb/qanda/1/"
```

It is known as a valid URL and all fine. But my code doesn't work when [there is a Persian character in the URL](https://3v4l.org/0C5Wh):

```
$url = "http://localhost/myweb/qanda/1/س";
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
//=> bool(false)
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137080/php-filter-var-filter-validate-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, basically because the string you've entered isn't a valid URL according to the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> "Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL"

Your client (the browser) will translate your character to `%D8%B3` which is valid and send that to the server, but your client will probably still show `س` (mine does).

So basically, the correct URL would be validated like so:

```
$url = "http://localhost/myweb/qanda/1/%D8%B3";
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

You can safely use [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/urlencode) to translate foreign characters.

Comment: Of course it is; you shouldn't use urlencode on your entire string - only on the relevant part of your url: `$url = 'http://localhost/myweb/qanda/1/' . urlencode("س")` - encoding your entire string will encode slashes and the colon too.

Comment: what should I do if my whole url is a variable? Should I split based on the slashes, urlencode each part and join the string?